# StringIO to capture log, but it's not written

Tags: python, logging, stringio

I want to capture log entries into a string, to display in a wx dialog. I just can't get the StringIO to be filled by the log entries... what wrong here?

```
# prepare logging
log = StringIO.StringIO('Report')
logger = logging.getLogger (__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(log)
logger.addHandler(handler)
# do something and log it
logging.info('Some log entry')
# display log
handler.flush()
dlg = wx.lib.dialogs.ScrolledMessageDialog(window, log.getvalue(), "Import Report")
dlg.ShowModal()
log.close()
```

The dialog shows the initial StringIO content ('Report'), but nothing added via the log ('Some log entry').

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534245/python-logging-to-stringio-handler) without enlightenment, and read the logging tutorials without hunches, so I turned here.

Thanks for pointers, nobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logger = logging.getLogger (__name__)
```

You are passing a name to `getLogger`, so it is giving you a logger with the specified name (instead of the root logger, this is important later).

```
logging.info('Some log entry')
```

You are calling *logging.info* (note: very different from *logger.info*).  `logging.info` logs to the root logger.  Which is a different entity than your `logger`.

Either switch that call to `logger.info('Some log entry')` or just get the root logger from `logging.getLogger()` by not passing it a string.

Reading back over this I just used the word "logger" about 60 times in about as many contexts, so if this is confusing I can try to clarify.

Comment: Thanks, "ing" vs. "er" sounds like a significant difference... So much for using the same name in different places. Works now, thanks for the hint.