# storing logger messages in a list

Tags: python, logging

Based on the accepted answer to this question:
[storing logger messages in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999627/storing-logger-messages-in-a-string)

I would like to accomplish the same thing, but send each each log message to a list.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already possible in stdlib by using a special-cased [`BufferingHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.BufferingHandler) instance.  If you use an infinite buffer, it will never flush.

```
>>> myhandler = logging.handlers.BufferingHandler(capacity=float('inf'))
>>> logging.basicConfig(handlers=[myhandler]) 
>>> logging.warning("uh-oh")
>>> logging.error("boom") 
>>> myhandler.buffer
[<LogRecord: root, 30, <ipython-input-11-feb6b3c2bc6f>, 1, "uh-oh">,
 <LogRecord: root, 40, <ipython-input-12-fd4144525168>, 1, "boom">]
```